# Python - plot rectangles of known size at scatter points

Tags: python, scatter-plot

I have a set of points:

```
a = ([126, 237, 116, 15, 136, 348, 227, 247, 106, 5, -96, 25, 146], [117, 127, 228, 107, 6, 137, 238, 16, 339, 218, 97, -4, -105])
```

And I make a scatter plot of them like so:

```
    fig = plt.figure(figsize = (15,6))
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax.scatter(a[0], a[1], color = 'red', s=binradius)
```

Which makes this plot:

[image]

--

I am overlaying this with a picture, in which there is a spherical blobl at each of the scatter points. I want to fit this blob, so I am defining a rectangular region around the scatter points for the fit to be performed.

I want to see this rectangle on the plot, to see visually whether they are large enough to enclose the blob, like so:

[image]

Can I do it with `scatter`? Or is there any other way I can do it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37435369/matplotlib-how-to-draw-a-rectangle-on-image

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Although @ralf-htp's answer is nice and clean and uses `scatter`, as far as I know the scale of the markers is expressed in `points` (see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14827650)). Moreover, if you zoom in, the custom markers will not change size.

Maybe that is just what you are looking for. If not, using separate `Rectangle` objects also does the trick nicely. This allows you to specify width and height in data units instead of points, and you can zoom in. If necessary, it is easy to apply a rotation as well, by setting the `angle` attribute:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle

# Your data
a = ([126, 237, 116, 15, 136, 348, 227, 247, 106, 5, -96, 25, 146],
     [117, 127, 228, 107, 6, 137, 238, 16, 339, 218, 97, -4, -105])

# Your scatter plot
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.scatter(a[0], a[1], color = 'red', s=10)

# Add rectangles
width = 30
height = 20
for a_x, a_y in zip(*a):
    ax.add_patch(Rectangle(
        xy=(a_x-width/2, a_y-height/2) ,width=width, height=height,
        linewidth=1, color='blue', fill=False))
ax.axis('equal')
plt.show()
```

The result:
[image: scatter plot with blue rectangles]

Note: If necessary you can obtain the `Rectangle` instances via `ax.get_children()`.

Comment: Your answer is awesome and super useful.

Answer (score 1):

you can define the markers in the `verts` option of `matplotlib.pyplot.scatter` like in **[Understanding matplotlib verts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16189928/understanding-matplotlib-verts)** and https://matplotlib.org/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/scatter_custom_symbol.html

> verts : sequence of (x, y), optional
>
> If marker is None [ this is not entirely working, cf [Understanding matplotlib verts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16189928/understanding-matplotlib-verts)
>   ], these vertices will be used to construct the marker. The center of
>   the marker is located at (0, 0) in normalized units. The overall
>   marker is rescaled by s.

source : https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html

However i am not sure how to define exactly the markers you painted, you have to construct a `list` that contains the desired marker pixel by pixel

rectangle with `verts` :

```
verts = list(zip([-10.,10.,10.,-10],[-5.,-5.,5.,5]))
ax.scatter([0.5,1.0],[1.0,2.0], marker=(verts,0))
```

source : [Understanding matplotlib verts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16189928/understanding-matplotlib-verts)

Comment: In matplotlib 3.3.1 I get error `'<=' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'`. Setting `marker=verts` helped.

Comment: (but the marker is not changing the dimensions when I change numbers -> so if someone reads it, be aware of it)